# Making Custom TableviewCell with Checkbox

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I made an app with CustomTableViewCells. I set a UIButton on MainStoryBoard.

I would like to change the image of button when I tap. When I tap again I want the button back to original image.

I discovered that setting UIButton in custom cell is a right way. I can pragmatically set default image, but default image does not change after I tap the button. Is it close to the proper way to do it? If not, how should I?

I'd appreciate any advice that will lead to finding the solution to this problem. Thanks.

image: [MyMainstoryBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdAhR.png)

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.setup()
}

private func setup() {
    self.myButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "checked"), for:.normal)
    self.myButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "unchecked"), for:.highlighted)

}
```

Comment: when you tap the button, you should set the button's state to selected, and you should in your `setup()` method to use `. selected ` instead of `.highlighted`

Comment: I have set .highlighted instead of .selected, but it did not solve the problem. I edited the post and added the image which shows my MainSroryBoard and code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the .selected instead of .highlighted.

Comment: give sample at least, brief it more, for single line comment box enough.